# Repeat while loop after a condition in PlantUML activity diagram

Tags: loops, repeat, plantuml, activity-diagram

I'm dealing with some difficulties trying to achieve the proper look of the plantuml activity diagram. What I'm getting is on the left, I'd like to receive what's on the right, ie:

- more straight line of the loop
- single ending node

**reality vs dream**

[image: reality vs dream]

I've tried this:

```
@startuml
start
:A;
repeat :B;

if (C) then (yes)
:D;
stop
else (no) 
if(E) then (no)
stop
'repeat while (E) is (yes)
else (yes)

@enduml
```

but when using "repeat while" I'm getting the error "Cannot find repeat"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this nearer to what you are looking for?

```
@startuml
start
:A;
repeat :B
  if (C) then (yes)
    :D;
    break
  else (no)
    
  endif
    
  backward :again;
repeat while (E) is (yes) not (no)

stop

@enduml
```

[image]